# Exception AttributeError: 'flush' in python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, flush

I get the following error for python 3.2 when I use the following class to print both to the stdout and to a file. I searched the web and found a similar issue reported by someone else for python 3.2
   Here is the link . http://bugs.python.org/issue12020
 . Does anyone has work around solution for this problem ?

Exception AttributeError: 'flush' in  ignored

```
class MyWriter:

    def __init__(self, stdout, filename):
        self.stdout = stdout
        #self.logfile = open(filename, 'a')
        self.logfile = open(filename, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
        self.encoding = 'utf-8'

    def write(self, text):
        self.stdout.write(text)
        self.logfile.write(text)
        self.stdout.flush() 
        self.stdout.buffer.flush() 

    def close(self):
        self.stdout.close()
        self.logfile.close()

  logwriter = writer.MyWriter(sys.stdout,'svt.log');

  sys.stdout = logwriter
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.logfile.flush()` instead of `self.stdout.buffer.flush()`? You'll have to implement flush in your class and some more methods to make it behave like a real file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `self.logfile.flush()` instead of `self.stdout.buffer.flush()`. And why do you flush when you `write`?

You'll have to implement the `flush` method for your class and a few other moethods to make it behave like a real file also (`writeline`, `writelines`, `seek` come to mind). Note that in the bug report the `flush()` should have been `flush(self)`.